# (MongoDB) If there is data in the first $lookup go to the 2nd $lookup

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a pipeline query where I first $lookup users and if no users where found I want to $lookup deleted-users.

This is my implementation:

```
{
    $lookup: {
      from: 'users',
      let: { id: '$ownerId' },
      pipeline: [
        { $match: { $expr: { $eq: ['$_id', '$$id'] } } },
        {
          $project: {
            fullname: 1,
            profilePicture: 1,
            businessInfo: 1,
            userType: 1,
          },
        },
      ],
      as: 'owner',
    },
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: 'deleted-users',
      let: { id: '$ownerId' },
      pipeline: [
        { $match: { $expr: { $eq: ['$_id', '$$id'] } } },
        {
          $project: {
            fullname: 1,
            profilePicture: 1,
            businessInfo: 1,
            userType: 1,
          },
        },
      ],
      as: 'owner',
    },
  },
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: '$owner',
    },
  },
```

But the problem is if found in user and not in deleted-user I got back empty result. How do I fix this issue ?

Comment: please add some sample json data

Answer (score 1):

Use different fields for $lookup results:

```
{
    $lookup: {
      from: 'users',
      .....
      as: 'owner1',
    },
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: 'deleted-users',
      .... 
      as: 'owner2',
    },
  },
  { $addFields: {
    owner: { $concatArrays: [ "$owner1", "$owner2" ] }
  }},
  { $project: {owner1: 0, owner2:0}},
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: '$owner',
    },
  },
```